# What is a SQL Server data structure to represent several objects chained together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

Suppose I have two tables in a SQL Server database: `dbo.Companies` and `dbo.Contracts`.

Suppose that I want to represent a one-to-one relationship between companies and contracts to indicate that a contract has been awarded to a company. I would simply create a join table with a foreign key to `dbo.Companies` and `dbo.Contracts`.

The above scenario is easy for any experienced SQL developer.

Suppose then, that I want to do something similar, but each company to which a contract is awarded can subcontract out to another company, which can subcontract out further.

I might have a company called "Acme", which might subcontract to "Evil Geniuses", which might subcontract to "Evil on a Budget".

Or then again, I "Acme" might subcontract to "Evil Geniuses" which subcontracts to "Evil on a Budget, but "Acme" might simultaneously subcontract another portion of the same contract to "Falling Anvils".

One must bear in mind that a company may be involved in many, many different contracts at different levels, or there may be companies in the system that are awarded no contracts at all.

What sort of data structure allows me to describe these relationships in SQL?

**Edit:** I am using MS SQL Server.

Comment: I added the tag [sql-server] to your question. Please tag your questions appropriately. I know it's common for Microsoft users to call their database simply "sql" but that's the name of a programming language, not the Microsoft implementation of it. Something about Microsoft branding... I bet if they had a text editor they'd call it "word."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `contracts` table like:

```
contract_id primary key,
company_id foreign key (companies.company_id),
parent_id foreign key (contracts.contract_id),
*** contract_level,
*** contract details
```

`contract_level` is optional here, depending on the business requirements. The largest drawback of this query is the inability of finding the top-level owner of the contract in one query. This can be solved in adding a column like `contract_family` equalling contract_id of the top-level contract. The query to view all the chain will be like:

```
select * from contracts
    left join companies on contracts.company_id = companies.company_id
    where contract_family = ...
    order by contract_level
```

Comment: This can't work because you put `contract_id` as a primary key, which means we can only have one record in this table for each contract.  I think you must have meant to make that a foreign key.

Comment: I meant a primary key, contract_id being some technical identifier (from autogenerated sequence, GUID etc). The business contract number can be a grouping column (denoting a contract chain) or a column from the details (if may differ within the chain or be not unique across chains).

Comment: This looks similar to what we eventually decided upon.  It's basically a tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

The same as a one-to-one (or one-to-many) relationship is sufficient.

SQL allows for recursive traversal of such relationships.

I have not tested the following query, but it should give you a basic idea.

```
WITH RECURSIVE ContractHolders AS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Companies AS m 
    JOIN dbo.Contracts AS n ON m.id = n.ContractHolderId
    WHERE m.name = 'Acme'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.* FROM ContractHolders AS h
    JOIN dbo.Companies AS m ON m.id = h.ContractRecipientId
    JOIN dbo.Contracts AS n ON m.id = n.ContractHolderId
)
SELECT * FROM ContractHolders;
```

I guess you use Microsoft SQL Server based on your use of `dbo.` Read [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms186243(v=sql.90)) for more information.

Comment: "I guess you use Microsoft SQL Server based on your use of dbo."  Yes, I do!